# How can I take full control of github repo using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, github

I have a python code where I create/update a database file. I want to be able to access the file across multiple computers and control the versions. I have a Github repo with the file and my plan is to use functions within my python code to update or delete and replace the file in the Github repo. I can currently upload a file to the repo using the requests.put method but I don't know how to update or remove/replace the current file. As I am pretty new to coding/Github, I don't have the slightest clue how to do this, can anyone help?

Also, I want to make this automated (ie anytime someone uses the gui coded in python, at the end it will upload the new file to github) rather than having users run scripts or play with Git.

I repurposed someone's code for the upload shown below and tried to just add the requests.delete line so that i could delete the existing file and upload the edited one. For some reason, I am getting a "shah not provided error". I have no idea how the python -> stuff on the internet connection works so idk what the problem is.

```
def upl():
    token = "%s" # replaced with token
    githubAPIURL = "https://api.github.com/repos/**user-name**/**repo**/contents/**file-to-delete**"
    
    r=requests.delete(url=githubAPIURL)
    print(r, r.json)
    # the above 2 lines are causing the error

    with open("**file-to-replace**", "rb") as f:
        encodedData=base64.b64encode(f.read())

        headers = {
            "Authorization": f'''Bearer {token}''',
            "Content-type": "application/vnd.github+json"
        }
        data = {
            "message": "testing file upload",
            "shah": "**shah**",
            "content": encodedData.decode("utf-8")
        }

        r = requests.put(githubAPIURL, headers=headers, json=data)
        print(r.text)

upl()
```